# Fast way to flatten a list of list while only keeping the 1st element in each sublist

Tags: r

Consider the command that creates a list of list as follows:

```
myList <- list(a = list(1:5), b = "Z", c = NA)
```

This creates something like:

```
 $a
 $a[[1]]
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5

 $b
 [1] "Z"

 $c
 [1] NA
```

Now when I do unlist to this,

```
unlist(myList, recursive = FALSE)
```

I get

```
 $a
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5

 $b
 [1] "Z"

 $c
 [1] NA
```

whereas what I am actually looking for is the first element from each sublist , i.e.

```
 1
 "Z"
 NA
```

Loops are very slow. No loops please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you consider to be a loop.  e.g. I'd call this a loop, but maybe it's okay for you?

```
> sapply(unlist(myList, recursive=FALSE), "[", 1)
  a   b   c 
"1" "Z"  NA
```

If you do not want the names

```
> sapply(unlist(myList, recursive=FALSE, use.names=FALSE), "[", 1)
[1] "1" "Z" NA
```

Comment: You can never avoid the loop. It's always buried under there somewhere. You can never avoid the loop. It's always...

Comment: Hi GSee, that was very helpful. Is it also possible to get rid of "a b c" as the headers and be just left with "1 Z NA" ? Thanks!

Comment: @Joran- Agreed, but when I write the loop, it takes a lot of time, so I was looking for a pre-built function that has optimized that process for me already.

Comment: @VinayakAgarwal, I updated to show the use of the `use.names` argument.  More generally, you can wrap named objects in `unname()` to get rid of the names.

Comment: @VinayakAgarwal My comment was of the light hearted variety.

Answer (score 6):

@GSee's solution is perhaps the most common one that comes to mind, but there is also the `rapply()` function ("*recursive `lapply()`*") that achieves what you're looking for:

```
rapply(myList, function(x) x[1], how = "unlist")
#   a   b   c 
# "1" "Z"  NA 
unname(rapply(myList, function(x) x[1], how = "unlist"))
# [1] "1" "Z" NA
```

Comment: That's interesting.  I'm surprised I cannot figure out a way to get rid of the anonymous function

Comment: @GSee, I know! I was trying to figure that out too, but with no luck.

Comment: @GSee, one thing I like with `rapply()` (but not asked for in this question) is the `classes` argument. For example, stick a `classes = "character"` in this example, and only "Z" will get returned.

Comment: @GSee (re using an anonymous function), the problem is that `f` isn't directly followed by `...`, so positional args end up in classes/deflt/how. This works - rapply(myList, f=`[`, ...=1, how='unlist') - edit, didn't see this was discussed in the comment's to DWin's answer...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 rapply(myList, function(x) head(x,1) )
  a   b   c 
"1" "Z"  NA
```

Comment: Hi DWin, This gives same output as unlist(myList, recursive = FALSE).

Comment: Yep. I trusted my faulty wetware.

Comment: New idea... tested this time.

Comment: How does this differ from @mrdwab's answer? (I'm not saying it doesn't, I just don't understand where/why it would be better)

Comment: I thought it was more "economical" but after looking at the rapply argument list, I now see that that was not correct. It would look even more similar if the how='unlist' were dropped from his code, which would not change results since that is the default for that argument.

Comment: Ah ha! With yours I figured out how to get rid of the anonymous function: `rapply(myList, head, n=1)`.  I still don't understand why this doesn't work: `rapply(myList, '[', i=1)`

Comment: Try this: `rapply(myList, `[`, i=1)`  The backticks are more "functional" I guess. Ooops. They are not so functional when they get eaten by the SO display. Anyway, use backticks instead of single-quotes.

Comment: I'm wondering you tried it before adding a name to the 1 argument. It's interesting to change the "i" to "z" and note that it still works, since '[' is a primitive function and matches only by position. The only function of the "i" or "z" is to keep it from being positionally matched to 'classes'.

Comment: DWin and @GSee, I didn't think to use ` instead of '.

Comment: The fact that '[` doesn't work is really a minor bug in `rapply` - it should do `match.fun(f)`